# auto-update and email

Tags: 10.10, server, updates

I've got several Ubuntu 10.10 servers which should all be set to do automatic security updates.

Is there any way I could get them to send me an email when they apply updates (particularly if they fail)?

I'm using r-u-on to monitor availability, disk space etc but the security updates are very important and I don't have a good way to monitor them.

I could possibly script something myself but I figured it's the kind of thing that's probably been solved many times already.

Comment: Webmin has an email on update feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the unattended-upgrades package actually has a parameter for this:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

---

EDIT: in fact there is more than one way to do it, and it's documented in the server manual:
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/serverguide/C/automatic-updates.html

Comment: Problem solved? if yes, please mark your own answer as the best one.